# mysql - How to store a python list object in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, database, list

I'm working on an iOS shopping application. And I use python to write my backend.

As for the cart part, I want to store a bunch of product ids in a  `list` object.

By the way, I use `SQLAlchemy` to process sql queries.

As I don't have much experience in database design, I wonder what is the best way to store a `list` object into mysql.

I think this is a one-many relationship issue and I'm wondering **whether I need a third table** except for a `CartItem` table to store products' ids and a `Product` table to store product's id?

Someone said that `serialization` is a choice. What is `serialization`?

Or can I just split list elements by comma and store as a `string`?

I've referred some question answers like

[Store list of values (such as interests)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766322/store-list-of-values-such-as-interests)

[store list of IDs mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748610/store-list-of-ids-mysql)

[How to store a dynamic List into MySQL column efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917106/how-to-store-a-dynamic-list-into-mysql-column-efficiently)

Answer (score 0):

I recently did an app using python / sql alchemy for someone to place an order from a website. What I did was, create 2 tables.  One stored the items that the user was ordering/ordered, and the other contained the order information like date ordered, address, special instructions, order number. It was a 1-many relationship. When the user was adding the items they were placed in 'in progress' status, when he paid for them they were placed in 'completed' status. That way I knew what was in his cart at all times and what items had already been ordered. I kept track of all shipments / orders using the other table.

The webapp is up and running [here](http://tikkaty.pythonanywhere.com), you will have to login to test the ordering functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Saving a single string with comma separated id's is possible, but I think it's not a clean solution. It's actually an example of serialization = translation of an object into a format that can be stored and reconstructed later ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)). Especially in simple example like this, I'd suggest using a third table:

I don't understand what you store in table `CartItem`, but I'd use a schema similar to this:

```
TABLE product
-------------
id | price | name  | ...
1  | 10    | socks | ...
2  | 34    | shirt | ... 

TABLE user
-------------
id | name | ...
1  | John | ...

TABLE user_cart
-------------
user_id | product_id | count | ...
1       | 1          | 5     | ...
1       | 2          | 1     | ...
```

Single row in table `user_cart` is used to store one product/user relation.

Using `SQLAlchemy` you will be able to get user's cart by simply calling e.g. `User.cart_items` after some configuration. Check [backref](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.backref).